# JS goes past forEach loop before completing it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have some code in my controller, inside it I have a forEach loop inside of which there is a function that returns a Promise. After the promise is resolved I can correctly log the array it returns. 
Problem is javascript doesn't wait for the forEach loop to finish even though the controller is not async, and I can't figure out why...
I've watched plenty of videos and read the post but something is not clicking I guess...
Thanks in advance

```
exports.submitInv = (req, res) => {

  let status = {
    validated: [],
    repacked: []
  };

  // ...other code...

  console.log("1");
  status.validated.forEach(async invoice => {
    // repackInvoice() returns a PROMISE
    let temp = await repackInvoice(invoice);
    console.log(temp);

    console.log("2");

    temp.forEach(inv => {
      status.repacked.push(inv);
    });

    console.log("3");
  });

  console.log("4");
  console.log(status.repacked);
};
```

The console should look like this: 1, [invoice], 2, 3, 4, [...all invoices],
Instead i get: 1, 4, [], [invoice], 2, 3

Comment: The `.forEach()` loop is not expecting an `async` function, so it doesn't await the iterations.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, if it works :

```
exports.submitInv = (req, res) => {

  let status = {
    validated: [],
    repacked: []
  };

  // ...other code...

  console.log("1");
  status.validated.forEach(invoice => {

      const promises = [repackInvoice(invoice)];  
      Promise.all(promises)
      .then(temp => {
            temp.forEach(inv => {
                 status.repacked.push(inv);
            });
            return status;
      }).catch(err =>{
          console.log(err);
          throw new Error(err);
      })   
  });

  console.log("4");
  console.log(status.repacked);
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried it but the problem persists, it moved from the "forEach" to the ".then". The output is now: 1, 3, 4, [ ], [invoice], 2 - Maybe i'll just modify the code in a more radical manner to avoid the issue, even though i'd sill like to understand how to fix it